# mongoose validator for "required:true" is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose validator is failing to validate where it's "required:true".

Sample code for mongoose schema and model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let chargingLocationSchema = new Schema({
  values: {
    type: Array,
    required: [true, 'Why no values? Always provide values!']
  },
  chargingHours: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0.1,
    max: [24, 'There is only 24 hours in a day']
  }
}, {
  collection: 'charging_locations'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ChargingLocations', chargingLocationSchema);
```

Mocha test cases for mongoose validation testing

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const ChargingLocations = require('../chargingLocationsModel');

describe('ChargingLocationsModel', () => {
  it('should be invalid if values is empty', (done) => {
    let cl = new ChargingLocations();

    cl.validate((err) => {
      expect(err.errors.values).to.exist;
      done();
    });
  });

  it('charging hours should be within 24', (done) => {
    let cl = new ChargingLocations({ "chargingHours": 30 });

    cl.validate((err) => {
      expect(err.errors.chargingHours).to.exist;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Mongoose version:

```
mongoose": "^5.1.3
```

Error, as it's not making "values" as compulsory:

```
ChargingLocationsModel
    1) should be invalid if values is empty
    √ charging hours should be within 24


  1 passing (35ms)
  1 failing

  1) ChargingLocationsModel
       should be invalid if values is empty:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of null
      at cl.validate (tests\schema.specs.js:9:18)
      at D:\nodeApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1522:5
      at complete (node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1683:5)
      at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1716:20)
      at D:\nodeApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:800:11
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: Have you possibly added any path validators in your schema? Or is the schema above the actual whole schema used for test? Just to confirm for the sake of being able to reproduce.

Comment: actual whole schema is used for the test.

Comment: default: undefined  ,solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Mongoose type arrays have a default value of empty array. As per mongoose document, to override that define a default of undefined.  Refer to [mongoose documentation for arrays](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) for details.